# Só cadastra uma vez e depois para

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma loja virtual de vendas usando HTML/CSS/PHP para o trabalho do curso e estou recebendo o seguinte BUG:

Criei o código para o processamento do cadastro de usuário, quando crio o primeiro usuário dá certo e cria o dado no banco da dados. Funciona tudo lindo, mas quando vou criar outro usuário não dá certo, não cria.

```
<?php 
// Vai incluir/importar a função/método que está no Conexao.php
    include 'Includes\Conexao.php';

// Receber o login, senha, nome, cpf, endereco e telefone
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
    $endereco = $_POST["endereco"];
    $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];

// Consulta se o login já é existente no banco de dados
    $consulta = mysql_query ("SELECT loginUser FROM usuarios WHERE loginUser = '$login'");
    $linhas = mysql_num_rows ($consulta); // Coloca na variável um valor com a quantidade de linhas encontradas na consulta feita anteriormente

// Se o resultado for verdadeiro, se existir o login no banco de dados, ele retornará uma mensagem e volta para a página Cadastra_User.php
    if ($linhas == 1) // ou true - Se o login existir
    {
        echo "<script> alert ('Login ja cadastrado com algum usuario. Tente novamente!') </script>";
        echo "<script> location.href = ('Cadastra_User.php') </script>";
        exit(); // se for verdadeiro, o fluxo para aqui!
    }
    else // Se o login não existir
    {
        $cadastrar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (loginUser, senhaUser, nomeUser, cpfUser, endereco, telefone) VALUES ('$login', '$senha', '$nome', '$cpf', '$endereco', '$telefone')");

        if ($cadastrar == true)
        {
            echo "<script> alert ('$nomeUser cadastrado com sucesso!') </script>";
            echo "<script> location.href = ('Cadastra_User.php') </script>";
            exit(); // se for verdadeiro, o fluxo para e retorna para a página de cadastra_user
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script> alert ('Ocorreu um erro no servidor. Tente novamente!') </script>";
        }   
    }       
?>
```

O que aparece quando eu tento criar um segundo usuário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ver como foi montado o sql na segunda chamada, usa `mysql_error` para mostrar qual erro ocorreu

Comment: vc tem um campo auto increment? antes de escrever a mensagem de erro faça, `echo mysql_error();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente, esse tipo de erro de não conseguir cadastrar mais de um registro numa tabela é ocasionado quando você define uma primary key (por exemplo, no campo `id`) e esquece de colocá-lo como `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

O que vai acontecer se você não definí-la como `AUTO_INCREMENT` é uma inserção de um valor `0` para o campo `id`, já que você definiu ele como `INTEGER`. Quando não se tem `AUTO_INCREMENT`, o valor padrão de uma coluna `INTEGER` não informada é sempre `0`.

Ou seja, você está esperando que o `MYSQL` incremente para você, mas ele não foi definido para incrementar. Como você definiu `id` como `Primary key`, ao inserir o registro, o `0` fica como `Primary Key`. Se tentar inserir outro registro, ele tentará inserir como `0` novamente, mas isso gerará um erro devido `Primary Keys` não podem se duplicar.